# How to filter among a number of radio button for a radio button with particular label

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a text field , where i input the value to filter ....

```
<input type="text" name="filter" id="filter">

<input type="radio" name="item" id="item" value="1">apple
<input type="radio" name="item" id="item" value="2">banana
<input type="radio" name="item" id="item" value="3">grapes
<input type="radio" name="item" id="item" value="4">mango
<input type="radio" name="item" id="item" value="5">orange
<input type="radio" name="item" id="item" value="6">pineapple
```

if i input apple in text field, only radio button with apple has text value should appear , rest must hide . Is der any way to do that ?

Comment: There are many ways to do that.But have you tried any one of them.?

Comment: pls show your javascript code

Comment: yes Deepu .... i filtered multiple list box ....using jquery .....bt i am finding it difficult to filter the radio buttons ......

Comment: problem is , i need to compare the value entered and with the text values , bt i dont know how th loop through this radio buttons , actually i am stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [jquery selectors page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

"Attribute Contains Selector [name*="value"]"

```
var name2lookFor = $('#filter').val();
var $matchingElements = $('input[type="radio"]').filter('[name*="'+name2lookFor +'"]');
```

There are a lot of other selectors, just find the one you need. You might need a combination to make a bit more custom search, but this should put you in the right track.

Offtopic: An id must be unique, you cant call them the same in the ID attribute.

Comment: thanks Martijn ..... i found the solution anyway, instead of comparing the text values , i put the text values as the value for title attribute , and compared the title value with the one in the text field ..... selector i used the same as u di

Comment: Instead of the title, you can use the data attribute. Simply make something like `data-searchThrough="Some Text here"`. That way you cn keep the title to what its for